# Ошибка в SQL запросе: "У вас ошибка в запросе"

Tags: mysql, sql, modx

Установлена CMS ModX Evolution

В админке выводит такую ошибку:

> Execution of a query to the database failed - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'groups ON groups.document_group=dgn.id AND groups.document='48' ORDER BY name' at line 1

> У вас ошибка в запросе. Изучите документацию по используемой версии MySQL на предмет корректного синтаксиса около 'groups ON groups.document_group=dgn.id AND groups.document='48' ORDER BY name LI' на строке 1

Ругается на такой запрос:

> SELECT dgn.*, groups.id AS link_id FROM u107423609_ldserv.`modx_documentgroup_names` AS dgn LEFT JOIN u107423609_ldserv.`modx_document_groups` AS groups ON groups.document_group=dgn.id AND groups.document='48' ORDER BY name

Что не так в этом запросе? Буду очень благодарен за помощь!

Comment: [MySQL 8.0 Reference Manual  /  Language Structure  /  Keywords and Reserved Words # G](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/keywords.html#keywords-8-0-detailed-G)

Comment: @Akina я буду вам очень благодарен если вы укажете как нужно сделать правильно.

Comment: подозреваю что слово groups зарезервированное и нельзя так называть таблицу /алиас

Comment: *как нужно сделать правильно* 1) Изучить весь список зарезервированных слов; 2) Никогда их не использовать кроме как по делу. Алиас (таблицы, поля) - это не по делу.

Comment: Измените название алиаса в вашем запросе. Если это легаси-код, на поддержке, то придется изменить код так, чтобы в результирующем тексте запроса алиас был обернут обратными кавычками